# Confused by JavaScript predicate syntax

Tags: javascript

In a typescript component file, the underscore.js library is being imported as follows:

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
```

Later in the component, the instructor uses the following line to delete a photo object from an array of photo objects:

```
this.photos.splice(_.findIndex(this.photos, { id: id }), 1)
```

I believe this line is doing the same thing as the following code:

```
var i = _.findIndex(this.photos, (photo) => {
  photo.id == id;
});
this.photos.splice(i, 1);
```

What I don't understand is how

```
(photo) => { photo.id == id; }
```

gets reduced to

```
{ id: id }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with LINQ.

Comment: Look at the source code of `_.findIndex` ?

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt.

The following is a function taking one argument (`photo`) that compares the `id` attribute on this argument witht he `id` variable of the closure context, and returns nothing:

```
(photo) => { photo.id == id; }
```

However you probably meant this:

```
(photo) => photo.id == id
```

which is not the same! This is equivalent to this is:

```
(photo) => { return photo.id == id; }
```

and just syntactic sugar. It is a function that takes one argument (`photo`) and returns the result of the `==` comparsion of the attribute `id` on this argument and the `id` variable of the closure context.

Next, this is just a object with an attribute `id`:

```
{ id: id }
```

the magic that makes it to behave similar is entirely up to `underscore`. Its not part of javascript at all.

[here](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L93) in the source code the two options are split. so basically thats two "overloads", that are implemented differently but behave the same way.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you. It hadn't occurred to me that it was just an overload. And you're right -- that is what I meant. I'm still getting used to the fat arrow syntax.